# how convert unix timestamp to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to convert this unix timestamp 
**1415115303410**
in DateTime, in this way:

```
private static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(long unixTimeStamp)
{
        System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
        dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddMilliseconds(unixTimeStamp);
        return dtDateTime;
}
```

But I get a wrong date:
**Date: {04/11/0045 00:00:00}**

NOTE: **dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp)** throws an exception.. my number is in Milliseconds.

with this online conversion tool http://www.epochconverter.com/ I get the right conversion:

**04/11/2014 15:35:03 GMT+0:00**

How I can convert this one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa

Comment: So I'd say you need AddSeconds instead?

Comment: @JoãoMiguelBrandão it isn't a duplicate because the conversion in that article doesn't work

Comment: @JoãoMiguelBrandão AddSeconds throws an exception, 1415115303410 is in milliseconds

Comment: Are you sure you calling this method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you convert epoch time in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883576/how-do-you-convert-epoch-time-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Well then the question is wrong if the number you ant to convert is not a unixtimestamp.
Divide by 1000 and then it will be a unixtimestamp you can convert

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is working just fine, as is. Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l9CSx7).

Everyone that is telling you to use `AddSeconds` is wrong. The number you are giving us is clearly in milliseconds. There are 31,536,000 seconds in a year. 1415115303410 divided by 31536000 is 4487. There hasn't been 4,487 years passed since 1/1/1970.

Comment: This gives the right date but the wrong time. This date: 1503583200123 is August 25th 2017 at 9AM but your code gives my August 25th 2017 at 2PM

Comment: @DevShadow This is probably a time zone issue. In my fiddle, I am using UTC time. 2PM is probably the correct time in your time zone.

Comment: **Lesson learnt**: Be careful if you are in millisecs. or secs. as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24106694/1705829)

Comment: unix timestamp is the number of seconds since 1 Jan 1970 00:00 UTC
so you may ned to correct to your timezone

Answer (score 9):

Just use DateTimeOffset

`DateTimeOffset date = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(1415115303410)`

Answer (score 8):

use AddSeconds instead of AddMilliseconds

```
 private static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(long unixTimeStamp) 
 {
    System.DateTime dtDateTime = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp);
    return dtDateTime;
 }
```

Comment: How I already said, AddSeconds throws an exception, my number is in milliseconds

Comment: is it so difficult to divide by 1000 an turn it into seconds ?

Answer (score 3):

```
public DateTime FromUnixTime(long unixTime)
{
    var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    return epoch.AddMilliseconds(unixTime);
}

var date = FromUnixTime(1415115303410); // 11/4/2014 3:35:03 PM
```

Since your number is in milliseconds, [Unix time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2883645/1361084), use `AddMilliseconds`.

Comment: I dont see how this is any different from what OP posted.  It does work however.  I think as @icemanind says, OP's code already works.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/pGF3km

Comment: Correct, this is just the same, I thought he had `AddSeconds` there (got confused from the last edits), still, this is the correct answer...

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt64("1415115303410"));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft continue thinking about us! All solutions to add seconds/milliseconds is not working with Visual Studio 2017 (.Net 4.6.1). But there is a new solution:

---

```
public static DateTime numStrToDate(String val)
{
    DateTime dRet = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    long dSec;
    if (long.TryParse(val, out dSec))
    {
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(dSec*10l);
        dRet = dRet.Add(ts);
    }
    return dRet;
}
```

---

If you need a UTC time - just add 'System.DateTimeKind.Utc' to the DateTime constructor call.

Answer (score 0):

Date to Timestamp

```
 DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(date_string, "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss", null);
 Double timestamp = Math.Truncate((date.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds);
```

Timestamp to Date

```
 DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
 dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(Double.Parse(arrayFinalResponse[i, 5])).ToLocalTime();
 String date = dtDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do the conversion by using a little trick with date command. 
It does depend on your timezone. I live in UTC + 1 so for me it is like this:

```
h1x1binax:~ # date -d "Thu Jan  1 01:00:00 CET 1970 + 1415115303410 second"
Thu Mar 21 09:16:50 CET 46813
h1x1binax:~ #
```

So that's not a unixtime timestamp ... it is probably in milliseconds so need to divide by 1000

```
h1x1binax:~ # date -d "Thu Jan  1 01:00:00 CET 1970 + 1415115303 second"
Tue Nov  4 16:35:03 CET 2014
h1x1binax:~ #
```