# Pagination in ListView (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, pagination, uwp

I have UWP where I have ListView on xaml.

Here is code how I receive json, set it to List

```
 public class TopPostsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Child> postsList;

    public List<Child> PostsList
    {
        get { return postsList; }
        set { postsList = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public TopPostsViewModel()
    {
        Posts_download();
    }


    public async void Posts_download()
    {
        string url = "https://www.reddit.com/top/.json?count=50";

        var json = await FetchAsync(url);


        RootObject rootObjectData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        PostsList = new List<Child>(rootObjectData.data.children);


    }
    private async Task<string> FetchAsync(string url)
    {
        string jsonString;

        using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return jsonString;
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

}

In XAML I show it Like this:

```
 <ListView x:Name="OrderList"  ItemsSource="{Binding PostsList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="GridInf" Height="204" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                    <Image x:Name="Image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200"  Width="200" Tapped="Image_Tapped">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding data.thumbnail}" />
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding data.title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="252,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="134" Width="1028"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="252,139,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="97" Width="218">
                        <Run Text="Comments:  "/>
                        <Run Text="{Binding data.num_comments}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="470,134,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="102" Width="312"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="787,139,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="97" Width="493">
                        <Run Text="Author:   "/>
                        <Run Text="{Binding data.author}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>



</Grid>
```

I need to paginate this ListView - show only 10 posts per page (now I have 50 posts in my List)

How I can do this?

Comment: So okay. I check it and install via NuGet.

When I use this `<telerikPrimitives:RadPaginationControl PageProvider="{Binding ElementName=OrderList}" Height="30" Margin="450"/>` 

It's only switching items in ListBox.

I need to show 10 Items per page. And switching from first ten to second. How I can Realize this?@JustinXL

Comment: @Logan When do you want to show the next 10 items?

Comment: Look, now I show all items from List (50 items)

I need to show 10 items by default, but have smth like button, that will update my xaml with new 10 items and etc. @VijayNirmal

Comment: @Logan Use two List(One is for all items and another is for the 10 items to be displayed). Use `(from p in _people
                      select p).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize)` this line of code to get the next 10 items to be displayed

Comment: How I can implement this?@VijayNirmal

Comment: @Logan I will explain it with the code. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two List(One is for all items and another is for the 10 items to be displayed)

```
private List<ItemSource> postsList = new List<ItemSource>(); //Given List
private List<ItemSource> displayPostsList = new List<ItemSource>(); //List to be displayed in ListView
int pageIndex = -1;
int pageSize = 10; //Set the size of the page

private void NextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pageIndex++;
    displayPostsList = postsList.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
}

private void PreviousButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pageIndex--;
    displayPostsList = postsList.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
}

//Call NextButton_Click in page Constructor to show defalut 10 items
NextButton_Click(null, null);
```

Don't forget to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` in order to update the ListViewItems (OR) Use `ObservableCollection` in the place of `List` and use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1328283/7331395) answer to convert `List` into `ObservableCollection`

Comment: Thank's so much it helps. I have also one question. Can you help me with this?

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643498/convert-unix-timestamp-to-normal-date-uwp`

Comment: @Logan If this answer helps consider Mark as Answer

Comment: This is such a hack and totally defects the purpose of pagination.